# Form method 'POST' causing widget to stop displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask, jquery-ui-datepicker

Relevant portion of html:

```
        <h1>Create KML</h1>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="demo">
            <form action="" method="post">
            <p id="basicExample">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Start Date" class="date start" value="{{ request.form.datestart }}"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" class="time start" value="{{ request.form.timestart }}"/> to
                <input type="text" placeholder="End Time" class="time end" value="{{ request.form.timeend }}"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="End Date" class="date end" value="{{ request.form.dateend }}"/>
            </p>
            <p>
              <button type="submit">Create</button>
            </form>
              Create KML file of points in selected time range. This file can be opened with Google Earth.
            </p>
        </div>

        <!-- Script for date time picker -->
        <script>
            $('#basicExample .time').timepicker({
                'showDuration': true,
                'timeFormat': 'g:ia'
            });

            $('#basicExample .date').datepicker({
                'format': 'm/d/yyyy',
                'autoclose': true
            });
            $(document).ready(ready);

            var basicExampleEl = document.getElementById('basicExample');
            var datepair = new Datepair(basicExampleEl);
        </script>
        <!-- END Script for date time picker -->
```

For some reason whenever I wrap the inputs with the below the calendar and time picker stop functioning?

!! Edited to show changes and location of form post method tag.

Also, here's my flask route:

```
@app.route('/create_kml',methods=['GET','POST'])
def create_kml():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.form['date start']
    return render_template('create_kml.html')
```

The date / time picker remains now, but when pressing the submit it returns a BAD REQUEST.

[image: header debug screenshot]

Comment: Is your console in the browser shows any error messages?

Comment: Where do you put the `form` tag?

Comment: @KennyPowers are you using with angular.js.?

Comment: No, just bootstrap / jquery for this form. The location of the form tag is updated in the original post. And the console is not displaying anything at this point. Just the 400 error in the main browser window.